# Call Java method in HTML

Tags: java, html

This is what I am trying to do:

I have written a Java program which requires two file paths as input parameters. The code is working fine and accurate. The problem here is that every time I need to give the complete file path in command prompt. So what I thought is to link this with a HTML page which will give you two browse button in order to browse file.

Now my problem is how to give the two browsed file path in a Java method. I had written entire Java code in batch file as of now. I tried using `<input type=file>` in HTML, but how to pass this value in Java that I am unaware of?

Comment: That's not how HTML and Java integration works. If you are putting this on a web site, where is your Java program going to run? On the user's desktop? If so, you need an applet that is trusted to perform this activity.

Comment: just add a .bat batch file that will call your Java program

Comment: Hi Vineet, this is not for a website it is just for running java method on local desktop, but for a layman It would be difficult to open command prompt and type  file paths. So It tought of using a GUI. Any  suggestions ?

Comment: use Swing if you want a GUI for using the code on a local desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this application is to be used on the desktop you don't need servlets or HTML, simply pop up two JFileChoosers and select the files using these.

The code to do this is:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f1 = fc.getSelectedFile();
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f2 = fc.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(f1.getName());
        System.out.println(f2.getName());
        /* make sure to make some checks to the files f1, f2 */
    }
}
```

Have fun! :D

Answer (score 4):

You can build a [servlet](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html) for this. Once you browse for files in html submit your html form to that servlet which does operation on that files. To point to that servlet give its relative url in action parameter of form tag. Or if you do not want to go in web development using server then use Applet they can also be a medium for communication between java and browser.

Comment: Hi Harry,I dont want any my code to run on any server. I will try yhe option you sugested but I hope it does not require any server in order to host it.

Comment: @Vivek: then try applet it will not require any server.

Comment: Vivek: If you don't want a server. I assume you mean you want a desktop application. If that is the case you can host a servlet with embedded webserver com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer or Jetty

Comment: Thansk All for the responses. Seems like JFileChoser is a good option but I am unaware of Swings. So any pointers to help me understand swing will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: @Vivek: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ and for filechooser : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: With Jetty, you can run an embedded webserver with minimum effort. The you could write a servlet like Harry suggested and post to it from an HTML page. Swing might be easier if you don't know anything about Java web development.

Answer (score 4):

Make an entirely Java UI, using Swing/AWT.

You cannot use `<input type="file"`. My initial thought was that an applet will do, but [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154568/accessing-input-type-file-full-path-from-a-java-applet). You can still use an applet, but you should browse the file from java, not from the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Why not replace the web page with a Java GUI - Swing perhaps? You could use a `javax.swing.JFileChooser` to browse the file system, get a filepath, and run the rest of your program with that. It sounds like this would satisfy your requirements.